# How can I build a Django-webapp using Jenkins?

Tags: django, jenkins

I want to know how to build a django webapp using jenkins. 
What should be done while configuring a new job in jenkins.
Can the django webapp be built into a .war file which can be deployed in a container.
How can I build a CI pipeline for the django app using jenkins.
A step by step guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you can build war locally (https://pythonhosted.org/django-jython/war-deployment.html), e.g.:

```
jython manage.py buildwar --include-java-libs=/path/to/jython-standalone-2.7-b2.jar:/path/to/postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar
```

2. Create Jenkinsfile, replace `sh "echo TODO"` with the shell or groovy command to you are going to execute for deployment (to nexus or artifactory maybe?).

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build-war') {
            steps {
                sh "jython manage.py buildwar --include-java-libs=/path/to/jython-standalone-2.7-b2.jar:/path/to/postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar"
            }
        }
        stage('deploy') {
            steps {
                sh "echo TODO"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Create Mutibranch Pipeline job (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/).

Comment: I am using python3.x, I don't think jython2.7 will be compatible with python3.x

Comment: @ronan  there is also jython3 project (https://github.com/jython/jython3) but it seems to be abandoned, so I'd avoid using it.
If the goal is to deploy django application, I'd consider reading documentaion (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/).